# Open model in a given revision

Tags: tfs, enterprise-architect

Intro: I am using Team Foundation Server to manage the requirements. Every time I change a TFS requirement a new revision is created and I can always look up the contents of some given revision from the past:

Latest
 `http://mytfs:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/WorkItemTracking/workitem.aspx?artifactMoniker=123456`

Revision 13: `http://mytfs:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/WorkItemTracking/workitem.aspx?artifactMoniker=123456&Rev=13`

When I open my Enterprise Architect model (which is stored on a SQL Server) I always get presented the latest "revision" of it. Is there a way to open an old "revision" of a model in EA? Is this somehow related to baselining?

Background: I would like to place a link to my model in the description of my requirement, but opening an old revision of a requirement should link to the revision of the model that was at that time the latest. Naturally this requires to update the link in my requirement every time I change it to the revision of the model that is consistent with the requirement.

Comment: What does "old revision of my requirement" mean? Where is it stored? If you open that old revision I'd guess your model is already in that old state (by what means ever).

Comment: I have my requirements stored in TFS. With every change I perform on a requirement it gets an incremented revision number and I can open the requirement in all old revisions any time and the content it had by that point in time is presented to me.

Comment: Instead of commenting you should edit your question.

Comment: You'll need to add a bunch more info for any of us to be able to help you.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I reworded my question

Comment: @ThomasKilian I reworded my question

Comment: You TFS links are private for you or for people in your network. They don't work for anyone else.

Comment: @GeertBellekens They serve only as an example what the syntax looks like. They are not considered to be clicked by anyone here (they get formatted automatically as links).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not really an easy way to do this.
The model stored in SQL server only stores the latest version of the model, it does not keep track of previous revisions.

You would have to control the whole model to TFS, and in theory that would allow you to restore the model to a certain point.

One of problems here is that you would have to restore each and every package to the state of that revision, which is quite a cumbersome job.

Another issue is that the model on your SQL server would be reset to that revision, for all users, not just for you.

Alternative workarounds (given that you have the whole model version controlled in TFS)

1. Branch in copy model

   - Create a branch in TFS marking the state of a certain revision for the whole set of files from EA
   - Export your model to a .eap file (or another database model)
   - Link your Version Control configuration to the new branch
   - Do a getAllLatest from the copy .eap file
2. Rollback in main model (in case you really want to rollback the whole model completely to a previous revision)

   - Rollback the whole EA directory in TFS to a certain revision/date/label
   - Do a GetAllLatest in the main model on SQL Server.